# Select de Estrutura de Produtos

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Bom dia!

existe alguma forma de criar uma query que traga o "produto" e todos os "Componentes e SubComponentes" da estrutura deste produto?

Deixe-me tentar explicar melhor

**Estrutura**

Imagem

[image: Estrutura do Produto]

**Link da Imagem:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGNZ4.jpg

Formato texto

```
- Bicicleta
  |
  + - Guidão
  |
  + - Quadro
  |   |
  |   + - Garfo
  |
  + - Banco
  |   |
  |   + - Selim
  |
  + - Roda
      |
      + - Aro
          |
          + - Raio
          |
          + - Pneu
              |
              + - Camara
```

Tenho a estrutura do equipamento "bicicleta" inserida no banco de dados e preciso obter quem é o "produto" e todos que estão abaixo (Componentes[eCOMP] e SubComponentes[eCOMP]) ligando todos ao produto principal

Exemplo

```
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
|eCOD    |eDESC2    |eCOMP   | eDESC2   |
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
|01.0001 |Bicicleta |01.0002 | Guidão   |
|01.0001 |Bicicleta |01.0003 | Quadro   |
|01.0001 |Bicicleta |01.0004 | Garfo    |
|01.0001 |Bicicleta |01.0005 | Banco    |
|01.0001 |Bicicleta |01.0006 | Selim    |
|01.0001 |Bicicleta |01.0007 | Roda     |
|01.0001 |Bicicleta |01.0008 | Aro      |
|01.0001 |Bicicleta |01.0009 | Raio     |
|01.0001 |Bicicleta |01.0010 | Pneu     |
|01.0001 |Bicicleta |01.0011 | Camara   |
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
```

**Estrutura da Tabela**

Dados no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/202e38/1)

Dados em formato Texto

```
Cadastro de Produto [Tabela PROD]
pCOD     pDESC
01.0001  Bicicleta
01.0002  Guidão
01.0003  Quadro
01.0004  Garfo
01.0005  Banco
01.0006  Selim
01.0007  Roda
01.0008  Aro
01.0009  Raio
01.0010  Pneu
01.0011  Camara

Estrutura do Produto [Tabela ESTR]
eCOD     eCOMP    eQTD  eNiv
01.0001  01.0002     1     1
01.0001  01.0003     1     1
01.0003  01.0004     1     2
01.0001  01.0005     1     1
01.0005  01.0006     1     2
01.0001  01.0007     2     1
01.0007  01.0008     1     2
01.0008  01.0009     1     3
01.0008  01.0010     1     3
01.0010  01.0011     1     4
```

Dados em Formato SQL

```
CREATE TABLE PROD (
 pCOD varchar(15),
 pDESC varchar(100)
 );

insert into PROD (pCOD, pDESC) values
('01.0001','Bicicleta'),
('01.0002','Guidão'),
('01.0003','Quadro'),
('01.0004','Garfo'),
('01.0005','Banco'),
('01.0006','Selim'),
('01.0007','Roda'),
('01.0008','Aro'),
('01.0009','Raio'),
('01.0010','Pneu'),
('01.0011','Camara')

CREATE TABLE ESTR (
 eCOD varchar(15),
 eCOMP varchar(15),
 eQTD integer,
 eNIV integer
 );

insert into ESTR (eCOD, eCOMP, eQTD, eNIV) values
('01.0001','01.0002','1','1'),
('01.0001','01.0003','1','1'),
('01.0003','01.0004','1','2'),
('01.0001','01.0005','1','1'),
('01.0005','01.0006','1','2'),
('01.0001','01.0007','2','1'),
('01.0007','01.0008','1','2'),
('01.0008','01.0009','1','3'),
('01.0008','01.0010','1','3'),
('01.0010','01.0011','1','4')
```

Comment: Posta a estrutura das tabelas?

Comment: Inclua a imagem na pergunta, além de ficar melhor para visualizar, alguns links são bloqueados dependendo de onde acessamos o site

Comment: Vou adicionar a estrutura da tabela em formato texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível chegar ao resultado que pretende de duas formas: criando uma tabela temporária e ir preenchendo, linha a linha, a partir de um `CURSOR` (ou `loop`), que é mais trabalhoso porque terá que fazer a consulta por cada nível e em termos de performance (por norma) é mais lento, ou simplesmente utiliza `CTE`:

```
;WITH REC AS
(
    SELECT      E.*
    FROM        ESTR E
    INNER JOIN  PROD P ON P.pCOD = E.eCOD
    WHERE       E.eNIV = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      R.eCOD, E.eCOMP, E.eQTD, E.eNIV
    FROM        ESTR E
    INNER JOIN  REC  R ON R.ecomp = E.ecod
)
SELECT      R.eCOD
        ,   P1.pDESC
        ,   R.eCOMP
        ,   P2.pDESC
        ,   R.eNIV
FROM        REC     R
INNER JOIN  PROD    P1 ON P1.pCOD = R.eCOD
INNER JOIN  PROD    P2 ON P2.pCOD = R.eCOMP
ORDER BY    R.eCOD
        ,   R.eNIV
```

Pode testar aqui no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/202e38/17/0).

Comment: Interessante, não tinha pensando por esse lado, irei realizar os testes e fazer alguns incrementos necessários para ver como vai ficar...